# Reference to a Danish version of something on the TV series The Magicians

Tags: plot-explanation, reference, the-magicians

Main character Quentin was talking about some Danish version of a movie or TV show.

> -It's not sleight of hand if you're gonna use CGI.
>
> -Well, I'm sorry. It's just.. That's insulting to anyone who's ever done any kind of close-up magic, so...
>
> -It's the original version, the Danish version, that it's, like.. it's dark.
>
> -It's like 100 times better because the Danish people, they're.. they're, uh... they have a dark soul.

Is it known which series/movie he is talking about, or the monologue was just a part of introduction to his character?

Comment: Haven't seen this episode, but I'm assuming he means all those dark, critically acclaimed Danish dramas that were recently remade, most notably *The Bridge* and *The Killing*.

Comment: If this is related to CGI he may also mean _Kingdom Hospital_, where CGI was used. Although I have a hard time understanding the relation between the first two sentences (about CGI) and the remaining part (about the show) from this short piece of script. Can you explain what happens in the scene?

Comment: The scene was cut between sentences, see.. Quentin was talking this over with his therapist and those sentences are in flashbacks of a conversation during a party. There's no more to add. I can upload this scene to Youtube if you want.

Comment: @Lettmannen So basically there is no relation between these two parts of the dialogue? If so, I agree with Walt, simply because these series are newer and better known.

Comment: Not necessary non-related. It would be for best if you watch that scene. Unfortunately, Youtube blocked my upload. If you're intrigued, you should find it online (i guess i shouldn't post such links here). Scene starts around 00:02:15

Comment: Someone wanna mention which episode this is?  Is it 1:4 “The World in the Walls”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The situation when he talks about CGI and when he talks about the show are split with a dialogue with the therapist. These two scenes don't seem related:

- He talks with different people (in the second scene his interlocutors' faces cannot be seen but they have different clothes and hair)
- The following scene (after another dialogue scene) is done in a similar manner - it's the same party, but different situation.

This means that the only information meaningful for your question is given in this single scene when he actually talks about the show. These two sentences are little to go on, but they suggest that he probably talks about one of the recently remade Danish crime/drama shows, i.e.:

- [Forbrydelsen aka The Killing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_(Danish_TV_series)) remade into [The Killing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_(U.S._TV_series))
- [Bron/Broen aka The Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridge_(Danish/Swedish_TV_series)) remade into American [The Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bridge_(2013_TV_series)) and Franco-British [The Tunnel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tunnel_(TV_series))

Most probably he means the first one as it's more popular and (in my personal opinion based on watching only the original shows) definitely darker in tone.

However it is also possible that he means the movie [Brødre aka Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_(2004_film)) remade into [Brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brothers_(2009_film)).

Finally, chances are that the writer didn't have any specific movie or show on their mind, but rather was referring to the increase of [Scandinavian Noir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scandinavian_noir) popularity in the last years (mostly in literature, but also in cinema and TV), which is sometimes referred to as [Scandinavian crime wave](http://www.allthingscrimeblog.com/2013/02/27/the-scandinavian-crime-wave-surfing-in-siberia/) and resulted in a number of English-language adaptations of Scandinavian crime literature and remakes of their movies and [shows](http://theeurotvplace.com/2014/10/nordic-noir-and-euro-tv-remakes/).